# Can anyone explain what this simple Arm routine does?

Tags: assembly, arm

So, there's a past exam question that I don't have a clear understanding of.

"What function does the ARM routine below perform?"
The function is

```
int exam1(int array[], int size)
stmfd sp!, {v1-v6, lr}
mov a3,#0
elop: ldr a4, [a1], #4
movs a4,a4
addmi a3,a3,#1
subs a2,a2,#1
bne elop
mov a1,a3
ldmfd sp!,{v1-v6,pc}
```

Edit:
I don't under what each of the commands do in terms of how it edits the registers / reads from memory.

Comment: It counts the number of negative integers in the array. What part don't you get?

Comment: @Jongware why don't you explain instead?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make that clear. I don't get what each of the commands do in terms of how it edits the registers /  reads from memory.

Comment: Because an in-depth explanation of *each separate line* may be multiple pages long. Thus, it's more economical to explain only the parts the OP does not understand.

Comment: Ah -- per above comment, just find yourself the ARM specifications online. The pages-long explanation I referred to can be found in there.

Comment: Can you simply explain what happens. I don't want an in depth explanation of how everything connects and how memory operates, etc. I just need to know things like ldr loads [a1] contents to a4 and auto increments the address by 4 bits.

Comment: And you want to know that for each line of assembler, I got that. Read the ARM specifications. It's all in there.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if I can remember my ARM assembler:

```
int exam1(int array[], int size)

stmfd sp!, {v1-v6, lr}    ; store registers v1-v6 plus link register on the stack
mov a3,#0                 ; zero register a3 - prospective count of negative numbers
elop:                     ; loop label
ldr a4, [a1], #4          ; load register a4 from the memory addr pointed to by a1 (first param)
                          ; and increment a1 by 4 bytes
movs a4,a4                ; move a4 to itself, but setting flags, so negative flag set
                          ; if the loaded value was negative
addmi a3,a3,#1            ; if the negative flag was set, increment a3
subs a2,a2,#1             ; subtract one from a2 (number of entries to process), setting flags
bne elop                  ; if a3 did not reach zero, loop
mov a1,a3                 ; move the result (number of negative numbers) into a1
ldmfd sp!,{v1-v6,pc}      ; restore v1-v6, and restore saved link register as pc, returning
```

If you don't understand the meaning of the mnemonics or notation, or individual instructions, it's probably best to look them up in a reference guide.